# How do I exit Windows 7 Games Set Up menu without clicking OK?

Tags: windows-7

Yes, I made the mistake of clicking All Programs, Games. Now this popup menu appears and the black X in the top right corner is conveniently absent. The only visible option is to click `OK`. I don't want to do that. I can't find this entry in `Windows Task Manager` either.

**Question**: How can I close "Setup Game Updates and Options" without doing an immediate shutdown?

[image: Windows7_setup_game_updates]

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to hit the "Ok" button. If you didn't change the settings then your not enabling or disabling anything that wasn't already enabled or disabled.  Have you tried `ALT+F4`

Comment: Becuse, by clicking OK, I'm assuming I'll proceed with the setup process. I want to exit immediately.

Comment: ALT+F4 doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Its already setup.  Your being given the option to change the current settings.

Comment: It's impossible for the process that is running to not be listed in Task Manager. Have you looked at the processes tab and looked for something similar to `setup.exe`? You could also use Process Explorer or another third party tool to kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is running as "Explorer.exe" (i.e. "Windows explorer").  If you kill the explorer.exe task, it will kill the dialog you show, which is normaly triggered by starting Game Explorer and clicking on Options.

Game Explorer can be started with

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /E,::{ED228FDF-9EA8-4870-83b1-96b02CFE0D52}
```

You should see two Explorer tasks running;  the one using less memory tends to be the dialog you showed.